# Why MainActivity is declared static inside other Class?

Tags: android, android-activity, static

I followed a tutorial on Bluetooth Low Energy, and I have started to add my own menus, etc.
The question I have is, why would MainActivity be static and put inside another class.

The full tutorial is available on Github: https://github.com/kaviles/BLE_Tutorials

Below is the Scanner_BTLE class that contains static MainActivity.

public class Scanner_BTLE {

```
private MainActivity ma;

private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private boolean mScanning;
private Handler mHandler;

private long scanPeriod;
private int signalStrength;
private UUID[] uuids;

// ToDO add Runtime Permissions to activate it momentarily once user asks for scanning
// ToDo this is currently done in App permitions while in dedug mode, add the software in the code so //permisiions does not have to be done on phone
// ToDo see "https://andela.com/insights/how-to-scan-for-android-bluetooth-low-energy-devices-successfully/"
// ToDO Look at "B- or add Runtime Permissions..... " on how to add it in code

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
public Scanner_BTLE(Scanner_BTLE.MainActivity mainActivity, long scanPeriod, int signalStrength) {
    ma = mainActivity;

    mHandler = new Handler();

    this.scanPeriod = scanPeriod;
    this.signalStrength = signalStrength;

    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
            (BluetoothManager) ma.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
}


public boolean isScanning() {
    return mScanning;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
public void start() {
    if (!Utils.checkBluetooth(mBluetoothAdapter)) {
        Utils.requestUserBluetooth(ma);
        ma.stopScan();
    }
    else {
        scanLeDevice(true);
    }
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
public void stop() {
    scanLeDevice(false);
}

//ToDo Use the Callback to find only the sps UUID of Relay

// If you want to scan for only specific types of peripherals,
// you can instead call startLeScan(UUID[], BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback),
// providing an array of UUID objects that specify the GATT services your app supports.
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
    if (enable && !mScanning) {
        Utils.toast(ma.getApplicationContext(), "Starting BLE scan...");

        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Utils.toast(ma.getApplicationContext(), "Stopping BLE scan...");

                mScanning = false;
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

                ma.stopScan();
            }
        }, scanPeriod);

        mScanning = true;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }

    }
    else {
        mScanning = false;
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
}

private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {

                final int new_rssi = rssi;
                if (rssi > signalStrength) {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ma.addDevice(device, new_rssi);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };

public static class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    private final static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    public static final int BTLE_SERVICES = 2;

    private HashMap<String, BTLE_Device> mBTDevicesHashMap;
    private ArrayList<BTLE_Device> mBTDevicesArrayList;
    private ListAdapter_BTLE_Devices adapter;
    private ListView listView;

    private Button btn_Scan;

    private BroadcastReceiver_BTState mBTStateUpdateReceiver;
    private Scanner_BTLE mBTLeScanner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Utils.toast(getApplicationContext(), "BLE not supported");
            finish();
        }

        mBTStateUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver_BTState(getApplicationContext());
        mBTLeScanner = new Scanner_BTLE(this, 5000, -75);

        mBTDevicesHashMap = new HashMap<>();
        mBTDevicesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        adapter = new ListAdapter_BTLE_Devices(this, R.layout.btle_device_list_item, mBTDevicesArrayList);

        listView = new ListView(this);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        btn_Scan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_scan);
        ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView)).addView(listView);
        findViewById(R.id.btn_scan).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        registerReceiver(mBTStateUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

//        registerReceiver(mBTStateUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

//        unregisterReceiver(mBTStateUpdateReceiver);
        stopScan();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        unregisterReceiver(mBTStateUpdateReceiver);
        stopScan();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        // Check which request we're responding to
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
//                Utils.toast(getApplicationContext(), "Thank you for turning on Bluetooth");
            }
            else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Utils.toast(getApplicationContext(), "Please turn on Bluetooth");
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == BTLE_SERVICES) {
            // Do something
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Context context = view.getContext();

//        Utils.toast(context, "List Item clicked");

        // do something with the text views and start the next activity.

        stopScan();

        String name = mBTDevicesArrayList.get(position).getName();
        String address = mBTDevicesArrayList.get(position).getAddress();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity_BTLE_Services.class);
        intent.putExtra(Activity_BTLE_Services.EXTRA_NAME, name);
        intent.putExtra(Activity_BTLE_Services.EXTRA_ADDRESS, address);
        startActivityForResult(intent, BTLE_SERVICES);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btn_scan:
                Utils.toast(getApplicationContext(), "Scan Button Pressed");

                if (!mBTLeScanner.isScanning()) {
                    startScan();
                }
                else {
                    stopScan();
                }

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi) {

        String address = device.getAddress();
        if (!mBTDevicesHashMap.containsKey(address)) {
            BTLE_Device btleDevice = new BTLE_Device(device);
            btleDevice.setRSSI(rssi);

            mBTDevicesHashMap.put(address, btleDevice);
            mBTDevicesArrayList.add(btleDevice);
        }
        else {
            mBTDevicesHashMap.get(address).setRSSI(rssi);
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void startScan(){
        btn_Scan.setText("Scanning...");

        mBTDevicesArrayList.clear();
        mBTDevicesHashMap.clear();

        mBTLeScanner.start();
    }

    public void stopScan() {
        btn_Scan.setText("Scan Again");

        mBTLeScanner.stop();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `private MainActivity ma;` Well `ma` is no static variable. What do you mean?

Comment: Please show how you instantiate your scanner class.

Comment: Well.. show how you start that MainActivity.

Comment: It has to be declared static as otherwise you could not start an intent to create a MainActivity. It looks bad coding. That MainActivity class should be normally declared in its own .java file. This is all confusing.

Comment: It is made static as you now first can launch the MainActivity. After that the activity creates the scanner.

Comment: Because declaring inner class static would allow it to instantiate without instantiating its outer class

Comment: Hello BlackApps, I removed the MainActivity class after I ran the debugger and found that the debugger does not stop in MainActivity. So I thought the original coders moved MainActivity into Scanner Class and forgot to delete the MainActivity..... I will show you the instantiated Scanner Class.

Comment: Here is how I instantiate the Scanner Class: mBTLeScanner = new Scanner_BTLE(this, 5000, -75);